# Can anyone please tell me why my flood fill is causing stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, flood-fill

```java
public static int flood(int x, int y) {
    if(x<0||y<0||x>101||y>101||went[x][y]) return 0;
    System.out.println(x + " "  + y);
    went[x][y] = true;
    if(grid[x][y] == 1) return 1;
    int result = 0;
    result += flood(x+1,y);
    result += flood(x,y+1);
    result += flood(x-1,y);
    result += flood(x,y-1);
    return result;
}
```

The code never came back to the same coordinate, but it is still somehow crashing.

**P.S.** `went` is a 2d boolean array.

Comment: When asking a question about code, the **very first** tag you add should be for the language you're using, and you should provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Please [edit] your question to add that tag. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is a recursive function, it calls itself.

At first sight, it looks ok, but it "expands very fast".

In the first call to `flood(0,0)`, it will "stack" `flood(1,0)` which will then "stack" `flood(2,0)` ... which will then stack `flood(100,100)` and only at this point will the method return for the first time!

That means that the stack size is roughly 10000 before the stack (of methods to continue processing once the current one is done) starts to "shrink back" after that point.

The basics of your method is correct, and I suppose it will work for a small array size, it's just a too big stack for a default JVM.

Comment: How can I modify my code so that it will work for this array size?